# Concatenating twitter api get request while using variables

Tags: php, api, twitter

I have a lat and long saved like this,

```
$lat_value = $_REQUEST['latitude'];
$lon_value = $_REQUEST['longitude'];
```

When adding the variables to the `$getfield String` like this,

```
$getfield = '?q=test&geocode='.$lat_value.','.$lon_value.',1mi&count=100';
```

I keep getting this error,

```
"You must provide valid coordinates, IP address, query, or attributes." }
```

If it's a syntax error could someone please explain why this does not work to me.

Full request and Response code,

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$lat_value = $_REQUEST['latitude'];
      $lon_value = $_REQUEST['longitude'];

require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "XXX",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "XXX",
    'consumer_key' => "XXX",
    'consumer_secret' => "XXX"
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/search.json';
$getfield = '?q=test&geocode='.$lat_value.','.$lon_value.',1mi&count=100';

$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

// Response from twitter 
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();

 var_dump(json_decode($response));
```

Comment: Can paste in here the request body and endpoint?

Comment: I added more code for you. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/geo/search) says, you have to specify either lat, long, ip or query, and you are not specifying any of them. I don't see any of those parameters in your querystring.

Try with this query:

```
$getfield = "query=test&lat={$lat_value}&long={$lon_value}&accuracy=1m&max_results=100"
```

Comment: The lat and long are being passed in by variable on POST request from a form on previous page.

Comment: I am not meaning the lat and long sent by POST, I was referring to this: "$getfield = '?q=test&geocode='$lat_value','$lon_value',1mi&count=100'; ".  I don't see parameters "lat", "long", "ip" or "query" there. I just see "q", "geocode" and "count"

Comment: in that same line of code if you replace the $lon_value and $lat_value with the actual numbers it works fine.

Comment: Are you concatenating the with a period? It should be:
"$getfield = '?q=test&geocode=' . $lat_value . ',' . $lon_value . ',1mi&count=100'; "

Comment: yes im using periods, thats a typo in the full block of code. I updated my code to show exactly how it looks in my program.

Comment: But if you say that the same code works if you hardcode lat and long, it should work as it is now. Did you try printing the variables $lon_value and $lat_value? Are they OK?

Comment: Hmmm i don't see anything after submitting.

Comment: I don't understand how that code works. I just tried the Twitter API and it didn't work. I tried with the query "q=test&geocode=-34.9014759,-56.1876229,1mi&count=100".

Comment: ya man this is really annoying. I am trying every example I can find online. I can run a search for key words just fine. But when I try to use geo coords it does not work. I find an example using city if that works I am going to stick with that.

Comment: I am editing my answer now with a new query that you may consider trying.